# Open a as3 class file from the source path from within Flash Pro

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm prepared to take no for an answer on my first stackoverflow question ever. :)

I'm using Flash Pro and I try to use AS3 classes via the source path. I got the source path with classes working but when I came back the next day I realize I have to open the class file hidden somewhere in my lib folders. Well, of course I know where it is since I have the import path in the Main file but is there a way to just "click something" to open any used and referenced files? I tried to use the Project tool but that didn't have what I wanted.

Is there some shortcut to open used files?

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. I'm afraid the answer is **no**. Flash IDE is very weak as a coding tool. Try something that is specifically designed to work with AS3 classes: **FlashDevelop** (free), **IntelliJ Idea** (probably free, no idea), **FDT** (free basic profile, paid pro profile), **Flash Builder** (paid).

Comment: OK! Yeah, I had some pure luck lately with searching for solutions and tools elsewhere but this one not so much hehe. Thanks for the alternative IDEs though! :)